# Jquery Zoom Plugin?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, zooming

I seem to be having a difficult time finding a plugin that will zoom into my image while leaving the *rest* of the image at the same size.

The reason why I need it is because I am using an image map and trying to zoom into the image on a particular continent. Once zoomed in all the way I will replace the image I zoomed into with a new image and image map for that *particular* continent. I don't want the rest of the world map changing size when this is happening.

Does anyone know of a good plugin for this?

Comment: Well, that's confusing. To *zoom* is to *increase size*, by definition.

Comment: @adityamenon there is two terms - *zoom in* and *zoom out*, so zoom it is just changing level of details using same viewport and resolution by varing view field

Comment: @Justin , which way you want to zoom ? by mouse scroll ?

Comment: Well yes but you do know what I meant in essence :)

Comment: Looking for something closer to a zoom akin to google earth and zooming quickly into a continent. The user would have no control over the zoom except when they click on a continent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a tutorial that seems to demonstrate something close to what you want, along with instructions on how to get there: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/magnifying-glass-for-images-using-jquery-and-css3

Here's another: http://mlens.musings.it/

EDIT:
Based on Justin's comment:

> What I am talking about here is an actual zooming animation. Not just merely replacing it as I could have done a fade in animation.

Use jQuery's animate() method to achieve this.

Code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#zoomimage').click(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:'150%', width:'150%'}, 500);
    });
});​
```

EDIT: Based on Justin's next comment:

> Hey Aditya, only problem is that the size is affected. Is there a way to crop it as it grows so it stays the same size?

That can be done by manipulating the image's container to hide the rest of the image while it grows. Something like this:

```
<div style="width:275px; height:95px; overflow:hidden;">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="zoomimage" />
</div>​
```

The `overflow:hidden;` ensures that the rest of the image does not show.

Comment: Not looking for a magnifying zoom feature :) More like how you would zoom into a continent on google earth but user would have no control. Basically he clicks a continent on the world map and it would zoom in, replace the image and image map via ajax but I can do that onComplete of whatever plugin.

Comment: Okay. Well, it does not look like you need a plugin at all for this. When user clicks on an imagemap area with an #id, you just replace the whole map div with your image. Plugins usually offer far more complex functionality and this can be done easily with jQuery alone.

Comment: What I am talking about here is an actual zooming animation. Not just merely replacing it as I could have done a fade in animation.

Comment: Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adityamenon/xhH5x/) of the code I added into my answer.

Comment: Sure, I've made something that kinda does what you need: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adityamenon/xhH5x/1/). The problem of course is that it does not zoom into a location where you need it to. You might want to look at the code of those magnifying glass plugins to find how that's done.

Comment: Thanks Aditya :) Yeah... the issue I am having right now is the actual position of the image. Right now I am using ImageMapster to build out my map and it resizes fine using the resize method for imagemapster but now I need it to position itself as it is resizing. The code they have is $('#worldmap').mapster('resize', xsize, ysize, speed). I would need to change the image position on each step of resizing. I will play with it.

Comment: I am not sure how you can work this into imageMapster, but zooming in a particular location can be done by setting the positioning in .animate()'s options. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/adityamenon/xhH5x/3/)

Answer (score 0):

here's your solution, I use exactly the same also for map in my  project,

http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom

Good luck :)

Comment: Dunno, OP doesn't want to change size but that plugin changes size :/

Comment: @adityamenon What do u mean by size, in that plugin the image size remains the same (width & height)

Comment: I am looking for something more akin to what it would look like if you quickly zoomed into a continent on google earth.